# Reading in integer array sizes and fill with random numbers, using java.util.Random

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm looking to read in an integer "array size one" and then fill that array using random numbers between 1 and 10.

Below is my code so far. The fact that I have to read in the integer to give the array a size totally confuses me. How do I finish filling the array with the random number(s)?

I'm new to arrays and this is also my first time using `java.util.Random` too. Would greatly appreciate someone showing hows i'ts done so I can read over and do it a few times myself. Thanks.

```
public void createUI() {    
    createInput("Array size one");
    setButtonLabel("Submit");
}

public void processInput(){
    int sizeone = nextInt("Array size one");
    int [] arrayone= new int[sizeone];
    int randomNum;
    Random generator = new Random();
    randomNum = generator.nextInt(11);

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayone.length; i++) {
      arrayone[] = randomNum;
    }
}
```

Comment: arrayone[i] = randomNum

Comment: Why does the title include "Android"? There is nothing in this question about Android.

Comment: Yeh I was thinking that was it. My AVD must be acting up. It returns nothing when I try printing the array. cheers.

Comment: Sorry I use an AVD to run the programme, I forgot to mention that. Seems its the problem. I'll have to reinstall it.

Answer (score 2):

You are filling array with the same number. You must put 
`randomNum = generator.nextInt(11);` into for loop before `arrayone[] = randomNum;` 
and here you got one more mistake it is `arrayone[i] = randomNum;` instead of  `arrayone[] = randomNum;` because you must define the index of array.

Comment: As a note, in order to get numbers in the range from 1 to 10 (as OP wants), it should be: `randomNumber = 1 + generator.nextInt(10);`.

Comment: Thanks a million! I see so it automatically starts at 0 so I must add 1. thanks again